# problem opening a link within an setInterval?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why trying to open a link through `window.open()` does not work after the second interval?

In the example I show below, the link opens correctly without any problem due to the first interval.

```
var c=1;

var op='';

var i = setInterval(function(){
   if(c==1){
     op = window.open(link);
   }
   c++;
},2000);
```

however if I try it in the second interval as I show below, just ignore 'window.open()' completely

```
var c=1;

var op='';

var i = setInterval(function(){
   if(c==2){
     op = window.open(link);
   }
   c++;
},2000);
```

Why is this and how could I solve it?

Comment: Not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/s19cyn26/

Comment: It isn't ignoring `window.open()`. It's because of the condition `if(c==2)`. `window.open()` is actually being called on only the second interval.

Comment: *Could be* that you clicked on the page not long before the first interval fired. Some browsers with some settings require the document to be "interacted by user" to allow opening of popup windows.

Comment: I had to disable pop up blocking to get a popup at all. After disabling the blocker, both cases of first and second interval opening succeeded, but popup blocking behavior can differ between browsers. You may find the code is more suitable for an intranet with browsers configured to allow popups than production on the www.